# Different performance by different ML classifiers, what can I deduce?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, prediction

I have used a ML approach to my research using python scikit-learn. I found that SVM and logistic regression classifiers work best (eg: 85% accuracy), decision trees works markedly worse (65%), and then Naive Bayes works markedly worse (40%).

I will write up the conclusion to illustrate the obvious that some ML classifiers worked better than the others by a large margin, but what else can I say about my learning task or data structure based on these observations?

Edition:

The data set involved 500,000 rows, and I have 15 features but some of the features are various combination of substrings of certain text, so it naturally expands to tens of thousands of columns as a sparse matrix. I am using people's name to predict some binary class (eg: Gender), though I feature engineer a lot from the name entity like the length of the name, the substrings of the name, etc.

Comment: I would hope you tuned the parameters on all the classifiers you have tried, particularly the decision tree classifiers. Could you describe your dataset in a bit more detail?

Comment: Yes, I did try many parameters when tuning. The data set involved 500,000 rows, and I have 15 features but some of the features are various combination of substrings of certain text, so it naturally expands to tens of thousands of columns as a sparse matrix. I do understand how generally different ML suits different size of rows and columns, but in case you tested them all and got different results, I wonder what other conclusions can be deduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to visit this awesome map on **choosing the right estimator** by the scikit-learn team http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map

As describing the specifics of your own case would be an enormous task (I totally understand you didn't do it!) I encourage you to ask yourself several questions. Thus, I think the map on 'choosing the right estimator' is a good start.

Literally, go to the 'start' node in the map and follow the path:

- is my number of samples > 50?

And so on. In the end you might end at some point and see if your results match with the recommendations in the map (i.e. did I end up in a SVM, which gives me better results?). If so, go deeper into the documentation and ask yourself why is that one classifier performing better on text data or whatever insight you get.

As I told you, we don't know the specifics of your data, but you should be able to ask such questions: what type of data do I have (text, binary, ...), how many samples, how many classes to predict, ... So ideally your data is going to give you some hints about the context of your problem, therefore why some estimators perform better than others.

But yeah, your question is really broad to grasp in a single answer (and specially without knowing the type of problem you are dealing with). You could also check if there might by any of those approaches more inclined to overfit, for example.

The list of recommendations could be endless, this is why I encourage you to **start defining the type of problem you are dealing with** and your data (plus to the number of samples, is it normalized? Is it disperse? Are you representing text in sparse matrix, are your inputs floats from 0.11 to 0.99).

Anyway, if you want to share some specifics on your data we might be able to answer more precisely. Hope this helped a little bit, though ;)

Comment: Thanks, I have added some more details about my data. I did come across your recommended map, I didn't delve too deep into it before as I have a lot of data and the map seemed to play a large role in data size in determining the path. Nonetheless I will look closer into it. It seems to me though that in a lot of ML papers, the authors usually use a bunch of ML classifiers like fish-net and then accept the one with the highest performance. So my question isn't really about identifying the right classifiers but when I look at my results or others' what can I deduce with different performances.

Comment: Also in the map in the classification domain, simple logistic reg and decision tress are not there. And my linear SVC seems to "work", but I would like to understand why the NB performances (my data is based on name which is test(?) data) is much worse, what is it in my data or or learning tasks that resulting in low NB performance (while I see better performance in similar research using NB).

Comment: okay, now I understand your concern. Yeah, I would also guess (reading from your question update) that NB should perform well. Well, actually it depens a lot on how you encode your samples (do you do some sort of tf-idf?). Btw, do you want to predict gender from name, or was it only one example? Because if that's the case I cannot avoid to try to suggest something that's not even related to machine-learning, like using the sexmachine library from python, for example (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SexMachine/). If your problem is broader or your goal is academic, just forget about what I said ;)

Comment: Yes, that's why I was confused why NB did so poorly and tried to seek an explanation. Gender as class is just an example, I am trying to predict people's race.